# everyshi.sty is missing, how to install

Tags: pgfplots, installing, windows, everyshi

I'm trying to use the package pgfplots, and I have successfully installed it along with the pre-requisite pgf. Whenever I compile, I get the error message "The required file ...everyshi.sty is missing", and then nothing works. I am using a Windows (64bit) computer with MikTeX 2.9 (when I installed it, I only did the basic set up). I am using TeXnicCenter as my environment. Help would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Normally if you install just `pgfplots` it should install whole bunch of packages, but I think you are doing it manually without the `on-the-fly` option

Comment: I installed it in the "Roots" menu in the MikTeX settings window.

Comment: I resolved the problem. For anyone else who struggles with this, the solution I found was to just google for the ms package, download it and install by loading the everyshi.ins file into my environment.

Answer (score 14):

`everyshi` belongs to the [`ms`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ms) bundle, which consists of several packages by Martin Schröder.

If TeX Live or MiKTeX is used, you don't need to install `everyshi` as single package, such as by compiling `everyshi.ins` or `everyshi.dtx`. Instead, use the package manager (tlmgr or mpm, respectively) to install the `ms` package provided by both distributions.

Comment: If the compiler just complains that it can't find 'everyshi.sty', how on earth (except by losing half an hour googling, as I have just discovered) are we supposed to know this means to install the `ms` package??!

Comment: @JamieVicary Nearly every serious TeX package can be found on *the* TeX archive site CTAN, I guess you know it. Simply enter "everyshi" in the search field, the package homepage shows you that it's part of the ms bundle.

Comment: Hello I have same problem , I did what you said... still it is saying everyshi.sty is missing !!
Acctually  "ms " folder contains everyshi.dtx  and everyshi.ins  But not everyshi.sty  

could you please help me?

Comment: @Redshoes Run latex or pdflatex on everyshi.ins.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and solved.  If you use miktex just update it. Namely, just find miktex console and update. More explanations  is right here https://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex