# everyshi.sty is missing and I cannot find it in CTAN?

Tags: errors, packages

I am a beginner...

I need to install the package `everyshi.sty` but I can't find it CTAN nor MiKTex !

I installed the `ms` folder from CTAN containing `everyshi`, but it still doesn't work!

Actually the `ms` folder contains `everyshi.dtx` and `everyshi.ins`, but not `everyshi.sty`. Could you please help me?

[image]
Also I couldn't  find it in MikTex Package Manager(Admin)

[image]

Thanks for your kind helps.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate. The question has been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188205/136226). :-)

Comment: @genericFJS   I checked that answer you can see my comment there!

But his solution doesn't work for my case .... I am asking a slightly different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the `ms` (MiKTeX) package. Use  `MiKTeX Package Manager`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard. I couldn't find it there ... see  the picture

Comment: I had the same problem filtering with `ms`, because there are so many packages including the group `ms` in their name. Do  not filter and display by names.

Comment: Or filter, but display by names. You'll find it on the second page.

Answer (score 0):

For everyshi.sty, we need to download ms from CTAN. CTAN folder contains everyshi.dtx and everyshi.ins. Now, we need to create the everyshi.sty file from everyshi.ins using command prompt. Open command prompt -> give the location of the folder containing ms -> type latex everyshi.ins and run. It will automatically create everyshi.sty. Hope it helps.

Comment: could you tell us, how your answer is different from the already present answer (except for the fact that this now involves using `cmd-line` interface?