# Format frame of listings

Tags: listings, framed

please, how should I set frame of listlings like line not line at bottom and dash on sides. Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}\vskip-4pt}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
\lstset{frame=lrb,xleftmargin=\fboxsep,xrightmargin=-\fboxsep}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Soubor}

\newcommand{\listingsfont}{\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[caption=\textbf{Vstupní soubor \texttt{.SPD} programu SPEL (pro první čáru)}, label=c_1, basicstyle=\footnotesize\linespread{0.2}\listingsfont]{spd.txt}

\end{document}
```

---

I am grateful for @BambOo 's help and his code. Now I have a problem with compilation of this code. There is maybe a problem with packages - everyshi.sty is missing. I didn't find it in MiKTex Console. I use TexMaker. Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}


\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Soubor}

\newcommand{\listingsfont}{\ttfamily}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcbinputlisting[]{\mylisting}[2][]{listing file={#2},title=Listing,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,listing only,#1}


\begin{document}

\mylisting[]{spd.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, you can have a look a https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings or at the package documentation for a full description of the options http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf

Comment: So frame=single? It looks like same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a fine definition of the listings graphical options, you can use the nice `tcolorbox` package which has a `listings` library defining the `\newtcbinputlisting` macro, have a look at the `tcolorbox` documentation at page 298 Section 15.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}\vskip-4pt}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
\lstset{xleftmargin=\fboxsep,xrightmargin=-\fboxsep}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Soubor}

\newcommand{\listingsfont}{\ttfamily}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcbinputlisting[]{\mylisting}[2][]{listing file={#2},title=Listing,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,listing only,#1}

\begin{filecontents*}{spd.txt}
HJD-2400000         RV                  weight ...
55836.5692          -13.1464            1.00   ...
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[caption=\textbf{Vstupní soubor \texttt{.SPD} programu SPEL (pro první čáru)}, label=c_1, basicstyle=\footnotesize\linespread{0.2}\listingsfont]{spd.txt}

\mylisting[]{spd.txt}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
To authorize the breaking of the listing, add `\tcbuselibrary{breakable}` to your preamble after `\usepackage{tcolorbox}` then add `breakable` in `\newtcbinputlisting[]{\mylisting}[2][]{...`

**EDIT**
Final version including `breakable` and the `caption` definition.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}\vskip-4pt}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
\lstset{xleftmargin=\fboxsep,xrightmargin=-\fboxsep}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Soubor}

\newcommand{\listingsfont}{\ttfamily}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter] % <-- to activate the counter
{\mylisting}[2][]{
listing file={#2}, % <-- argument in {} of \mylisting is the filename
title=Listing,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,listing only,
breakable, % <-- table can span multiple pages
title={Soubor \thetcbcounter: #1}} % <-- argument in [] of \mylisting is the title with counter

\begin{filecontents*}{spd.txt}
HJD-2400000         RV                  weight ...
55836.5692          -13.1464            1.00   ...
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\mylisting[SPD]{spd.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChvQU.png - Here is the problem.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPXos.png

Comment: I can't find this file in MiKTex Console https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPXos.png

Comment: Actually, your snippet works for me except for the `spd.txt` file which I added with `filecontents`. Can you do `pdflatex <yourfilename>.tex` in a command window to see what the error is

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0UhN.png and after install https://i.stack.imgur.com/84V3Z.png

Comment: I hope http://leteckaposta.cz/514466375 - here are files

Comment: Sorry, but I won't open external files. Are you using a specific editor (for example `texmaker`) with a master file option activated maybe ? By the way, you should edit your answer to add all relevant information instead of linking towards external information, it's a safer practice

Comment: Ok, try to install the `ms` package with `miktex` `everyshi` is a part of it https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170985/everyshi-sty-is-missing-how-to-install Or maybe you did already ?

Comment: Thank you very much. And is it possible to set that the listlings continues to another side? https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5DD9.png

Comment: I am sorry, please, the last question, how can I add numering of files a the word file. For example: File 2.1: name of file? Thank you.

Comment: Look at section 5 of the `tcolorbox` manual *Numbered boxes*. You will be able to tune the title of the box as you wish

Comment: I wrote 
 \newtcbinputlisting[]{\mylisting}[2][]{listing file={#2},title=Listing,colback=red!5!white,colframe=black!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,listing only,#1,breakable,title=Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2,#1}
What is wrong please? Thank you.

Comment: This code doesn't work too.
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,number within=section]{\mylisting}[2][]{listing file={#2},title=Listing,colback=red!5!white,colframe=black!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,listing only,#1,breakable,title=Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2,#1}

Should I write something to mylislings too?

Comment: I added the code for the final version in my answer with a working counter.

Comment: @Elisabeth could you solve your issue ?

Comment: Yes, you solution is perfect. Thank you very much!!!